# If "then" is never called for a function, is there a "fail" alternative that I can define?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using .then() on a function.

But in some cases that function doesn't finish with success, so I'm guessing that's why the then() is never called. Can I define another function that will be called in this situation?

I want to do something else, if the initial function fails.

Comment: Using `.then()` on a function... Is it a *promise*? A *thenable*? Does it have a `.catch()` ?

Answer (score 5):

> deferred.then( doneFilter [, failFilter ] [, progressFilter ] )

The second parameter is for that purpose.

```
$.get( "test.php" ).then(
  function() {
    alert( "$.get succeeded" );
  }, function() {
    alert( "$.get failed!" );
  }
);
```

Comment: completely forgot the obvious solution :)